# Two Struts2 Filters in One Web Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I want to use two struts2 filters in one application. I have following filters definition in `web.xml`. "struts2" filter is already there, I just added "companion" filter.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.abc</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<filter>
    <filter-name>companion</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>companion.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>companion</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xyz</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have created two configuration files "struts.xml" and "companion.xml" in class path. These files are completely independent of each other. I have also define constants "struts.action.extension" for in each configuration files with appropriate values (struts2 -> abc, and companion -> xyz). Some actions and their mappings are also available in both configuration files.

Now, when I access an action, it shows following message on my browser.

`Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /fetchUserInfo.xyz`.

Following log message is got from server log.

```
12/12/12 15:48:24.846, ERROR, [WebContainer : 0], Dispatcher initialization failed
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:144)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMethods(ContainerImpl.java:113)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:71)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:67)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:284)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:116)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:483)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:523)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:521)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:521)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:203)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:465)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:238)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:296)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:721)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:673)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:688)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:96)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:758)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:718)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3252)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:264)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:811)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1439)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:112)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:383)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:263)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:195)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:743)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:873)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1469)

Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.createParameterInjector(ContainerImpl.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParametersInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:225)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:287)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$3.create(ContainerImpl.java:117)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$3.create(ContainerImpl.java:114)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:141)
... 51 more
```

Is it possible to use two filters in one application? If so the what am I missing?

Comment: Moreover, I am using WebSphere 6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is resolved by defining `struts-default.xml` and `struts-plugin.xml` with `companion.xml`.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,companion.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13839585/1307229