# Struts2 Configuration file name in web.xml

Tags: struts2

http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1.2/docs/webxml.html

According to above link we can specify configuration file name in web.xml. so I have added `config` param in following mapping.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>struts.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now I am unable to start web application. Following log is printed on console.

`SEVERE: Dispatcher initialization failed`

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:144)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMethods(ContainerImpl.java:113)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:71)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:67)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:284)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:116)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:483)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:523)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:521)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:521)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:203)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.createParameterInjector(ContainerImpl.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParametersInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:225)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:287)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$3.create(ContainerImpl.java:117)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$3.create(ContainerImpl.java:114)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:141)
... 39 more

Dec 12, 2012 4:32:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory). - Class: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl

File: ContainerImpl.java
Method: addInjectorsForMembers
Line: 144 - com/opensymphony/xwork2/inject/ContainerImpl.java:144:-1
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:449)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.DependencyException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:144)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMethods(ContainerImpl.java:113)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:90)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:71)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:67)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:284)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:76)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:116)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:483)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:523)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$6.call(ContainerImpl.java:521)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:574)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:521)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:203)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:390)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:436)
... 20 more

Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MissingDependencyException: No mapping found for dependency [type=com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory, name='default'] in public void com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.setObjectFactory(com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory).
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.createParameterInjector(ContainerImpl.java:235)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParametersInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:225)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:287)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$3.create(ContainerImpl.java:117)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$3.create(ContainerImpl.java:114)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectorsForMembers(ContainerImpl.java:141)
... 39 more

Dec 12, 2012 4:32:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
Dec 12, 2012 4:32:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/theStruts2] startup failed due to previous errors
Dec 12, 2012 4:32:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/theStruts2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@104e104e]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@1fb61fb6]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Dec 12, 2012 4:32:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
SEVERE: The web application [/theStruts2] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10] (value [com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$10@10281028]) and a value of type [java.lang.Object[]] (value [[Ljava.lang.Object;@13d013d0]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define `struts-default.xml` and `struts-plugin.xml` as well inside `<init-param>`.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Without it Struts2 cannot find necessary beans/results/interceptors/etc. defined in `struts-default.xml` file. Of course you could copy all declarations from default file to your configuration file.