# Change default location of struts.xml in Struts2

Tags: java, xml, struts2, web.xml, servlet-filters

I've created a Struts2 project which is working fine when I place my `struts.xml` file inside `src` directory.

Below is my `web.xml` configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">    
    <display-name>struts2project</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
         org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

If I put my `struts.xml` inside `WEB-INF` directory instead, it is not getting loaded.

Please do not give answers as "it is irrelevant" or something else. I'm just asking whether (and how) we can change the default location of `struts.xml` or not.

Comment: What's wrong with the location you have used before?

Comment: He is a thrill seeker :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be completely clear, you don't even need struts.xml, the only *needed* configuration file is web.xml.

**From [Configuration Files](https://struts.apache.org/docs/configuration-files.html)**

> **From a Struts developer point of view, the one required configuration
>   file used by the framework is web.xml**. From here, you have full
>   control over how Struts configures both itself and your application.
>   By default, Struts will load a set of internal configuration files to
>   configure itself, then another set to configure your application,
>   however **it is possible to build an entire Struts application without
>   writing a single configuration file other than web.xml**.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> File      Optional    Location (relative to webapp)          Purpose
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> web.xml      no           /WEB-INF/                 Web deployment descriptor to include 
>                                                     all necessary framework components
> -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> struts.xml   yes          /WEB-INF/classes/         Main configuration, contains 
>                                                     result/view types, action mappings,
>                                                     interceptors, and so forth
> ```

To answer your question, however, it is possible to add configuration files other than the default ones by using the `config` initialization parameter in web.xml.

**From [web.xml](https://struts.apache.org/docs/webxml.html)**

> #### Key Initialization Parameters
>
> `config` - a comma-delimited list of XML configuration files to load.

So it is enough to specify the new struts.xml in web.xml to achieve your goal:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <!-- Edit after @AleskandrM's comments/answer because 
             1) every possible configuration file must be specified,
                otherwise they will be hidden by this setting and 
             2) settings are relative to /WEB-INF/classes/, and hence
                the /WEB-INF/ must be replaced by ../ and
             3) the order is important as well. You cannot extend 
                struts-default package in your struts.xml if it isn't loaded yet. 
        -->
```

```
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts.xml</param-value>
```

```
        <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,../struts.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

That said, I generally avoid this kind of customizations: you will earn basically nothing, apart from potential drawbacks that you might be the only one in the world to get, due to having left the main road.

Comment: I don't think `/WEB-INF/struts.xml` will work because location is relative to webapp `/WEB-INF/classes/ `. Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/13839153/1700321.

Comment: @AleksandrM Are you sure there is the need to specify every configuration file and not only the ones with a special position ? With my configuration I'd be "hiding" struts-default.xml and struts-plugin.xml ? It seems too overkill to me :|

Comment: I am sure. -> https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Dispatcher.java#L361.

Comment: A good way to trick a coworker in need of a plugin :P I'll edit the answer referencing your, after your is accepted

Comment: ...And the order is important as well. You cannot extend `struts-default` package in your `struts.xml` if it isn't loaded.

Comment: Added it too. What a mess for moving a file that isn't even needed in a place that should not even allow it :S

Answer (score 3):

The correct configuration to put `struts.xml` directly into WEB-INF folder is:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config</param-name>
      <param-value>struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,../struts.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Read Andrea [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30621025/1700321) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13839153/1700321) to find out why.

Also the order in which you define xml files is important as well. E.g. You cannot extend `struts-default` package (from `struts-default.xml`)  in your `struts.xml` if it isn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

struts.xml should only be in the classpath of the application . Its location is irrelevant.

Comment: You forgot to add *or something else*.

Comment: sorry, didn`t get you

Comment: `Please do not give answer as "it is irrelevant" or something else.`

Comment: @AleksandrM The *something else* looks like a hack and should be removed acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 2 loads default configuration files (struts-default.xml, struts-plugin.xml, struts.xml) using StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter).

To understand about loading of these files by framework -

These filenames are defined as constant in Dispatcher.class (used in StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter) file of Struts framework.

**DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_PATHS = "struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,struts.xml";**

**init_TraditionalXmlConfigurations()** method present in Dispatcher.class loads these xmls.

```
private void init_TraditionalXmlConfigurations() {
        String configPaths = initParams.get("config");
        if (configPaths == null) {
            configPaths = DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_PATHS;
        }
        String[] files = configPaths.split("\\s*[,]\\s*");
        for (String file : files) {
            if (file.endsWith(".xml")) {
                configurationManager.addContainerProvider(createStrutsXmlConfigurationProvider(file, false, servletContext));
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid configuration file name");
            }
        }
    }
```

To Override the default path setting for these xmls you can provide the paths of these XMLs while defining the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter in web.xml as answered by other users here.